# CSS not support arabic

Tags: html, css, fonts, arabic, webfonts

I have the following menu:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">Our News</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="services.html">Our Services</a></li>
  <li><a href="products.html">Our Products</a></li>
  <li class="last-item"><a href="contacts.html">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, when I use Arabic text inside the `a` tags, the text disappears.

As an example,

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li><a href="index.html">الر ئيسي</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.html">الاخبار</a></li>
  <li><a class="active" href="services.html">الخدمات</a></li>
  <li><a href="products.html">المنتجات</a></li>
  <li class="last-item"><a href="contacts.html">اتصل بنا</a></li>
</ul>
```

even though I'm using `meta charset="utf-8"` in the HTML page. My css code:

```
.menu li a, .list-1 li a, .button-2, .logo {
    text-decoration:none
}
.menu {
    width:100%
}
.menu li {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-right:1px
}
.menu li.last-item {
    margin:0
}
.menu li a {
    display:inline-block;
    width:196px;
    font-size:17px;
    line-height:1.22em;
    padding:18px 0 36px;
    margin-top:10px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:18px 18px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius:18px 18px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:18px 18px 0 0
}
.menu li a.active, .menu li a:hover {
    color:#0f0f0f;
    background:#fff;
    padding:28px 0 36px;
    margin:0
}
```

the template i use in this link 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/w5uf9wapenyitn3/myTemplate.rar

Comment: Your font does not support arabic perhaps...

Comment: I cannot see CSS in your question... :-?

Comment: I suspect @slash197 is correct. Try setting the font to one you know contains all the relevant characters.

Comment: i'm edit code and add css

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsbin.com/yeguwuju/1/edit?html,css,output). You're either *not* using UTF-8 (saying you do is not the same as actually doing it), your font doesn't support UTF-8 or you have further styles that affect the text.

Comment: i'm using Arabic font
body {font-family:'Arabic Typesetting', Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:100%;color:#9d9d9d;min-width:984px;background:url(images/body.jpg) center 0 repeat}

Comment: i'm using visual studio 2012

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario i'm using Arabic font
font-family:'Arabic Typesetting'

Comment: Are you sure VS 2012 is saving as UTF-8? Go File > Save As, then hit the arrow on the Save icon, choose Save with Encoding, then UTF-8. Do the same for *all* of your files (HTML, CSS, etc). Finally, is that font installed on your PC (it won't work if not), and if it's a webfont, is it loading properly (and can we see the CSS)? And what browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: Also, try putting `@charset "UTF-8";` as the first line in your CSS file.

Comment: also without vs2012 does not work, please download the template i use from this link http://www.mediafire.com/download/w5uf9wapenyitn3/myTemplate.rar

Comment: The key part of the code (presumably, the part where the problem was, according to the accepted answer) was not included in the question. This question will hardly be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is here with this file:

```
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It`s a font file , try to /*Hash*/ it  , and it will work
(Y)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the issue is that you are observing, however, simply specifying utf-8 as the character set isn't sufficient to support right-to-left languages. First of all, you should always indicate the language in your HTML (i.e. <html lang="ar">), and you should use the "dir" attribute to specify the text directionality (i.e. dir="rtl").

In other words, for an Arabic page, one would expect your HTML page to start with:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
```

For more info, see: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html

Additionally, for right-to-left languages, you'll need to fip your CSS code (i.e. replace "left" with "right", swap the right and left values in combined rules such as "margin" and "padding", etc.) for proper display.

Comment: actually i'm using 
<!DOCTYPE html>
and (<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">

Comment: Interesting. Do you have a screenshot of what is broken? And the devices / browsers on which you are seeing this?

Comment: please see the problem in my template http://www.mediafire.com/download/w5uf9wapenyitn3/myTemplate.rar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`

Try like this,

```
<li><a dir="rtl" lang="ar" href="index.html">الر ئيسي</a></li>
```

`dir="rtl"` means right to left

`lang="ar"` means arabic

Answer (score 0):

this is not clear what exactly you want.

for arabic langauge you have to define the direction so it will start from right to left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">
```

you have to use this. In addition I can see the arabic text in my local machine. check here[image]

Comment: please download this my template that i use from this link and try your self 
http://www.mediafire.com/download/w5uf9wapenyitn3/myTemplate.rar

Comment: I've found a reason why Arabic text was not appearing.
to fix this issue please open the "cufon-replace.js" and comment  the line number2.
    `Cufon.replace('.menu li a', { fontFamily: 'Open Sans', hover:true });`

 this line is creating a canvas element run time and that is preventing the Arabic text to rendering.

If you like my answer please vote it.